# TextString can not convert general TableForm

Tags: bugs, grid-layouts, conversion

**Bug introduced in 10 and persisting through 11.1.0**

`TextString` is new in 10.0

---

According to the Documentation

> `TextString[TableForm[list]]` formats a list of lists as space-separated
>   columns.

and

```
TextString@TableForm@{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

outputs expected result

> ```
> "1 2
> 3 4"
> ```

However,

```
TextString@TableForm@{{1},{3,4}}
```

outputs

> ```
> "TableForm[{{1}, {3, 4}}]"
> ```

Is this behavior intended? To me, this is inconsistent.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: According to the Docs, "`TextString[expr]` gives a human-readable string representation of `expr`." I don't think that the output `"TableForm[{{1}, {3, 4}}]"` is "human-readable" in the sense of the Docs for `TextString`. So tag this as a bug.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Very likely a bug : )

Comment: I voted to close this since the question "is this behavior intended?" is not something that we can answer.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, "list of lists" was intended to mean "full array". And, from the documentation for [`ArrayQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayQ.html): "A ragged collection of nested lists is not a full array."

```
expr = {{1}, {3, 4}};

ArrayQ[expr]

(*  False  *)
```

Pad the sublists with empty strings to make them all the same length and form a full array.

```
TextString@TableForm@(PadRight[#, Max[Length /@ expr], ""] & /@ expr)
```

[image]

```
TextString@TableForm@(PadLeft[#, Max[Length /@ expr], ""] & /@ expr)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for solution. `PadRight ` could be made simpler `TextString@TableForm@PadRight[{{1}, {3, 4}}, Automatic, ""]` +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the old method :

```
st=OpenWrite["fileName",FormatType-> OutputForm,PageWidth-> Infinity];
Write[st,TableForm@{{2},{3,4}}];
Close[st];
FilePrint["fileName"]
```

[image]

You can remove the extra line with the option `TableSpacing` of `TableForm` :

```
st=OpenWrite["fileName",
FormatType-> OutputForm,
PageWidth-> Infinity];
Write[st,TableForm[{{2},{3,4}},TableSpacing->{0, 1}]];
Close[st];
FilePrint["fileName"]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, andre, thank you for answering. But the output has extra blank line in between

Comment: @matheorem That's not a problem . You can do anything you want with the option `TableSpacing` of `TableForm`. In your case `TableForm[{{2},{3,4}},TableSpacing->{0, 1}]`, I think.

Comment: I think this proves that the behavior shown in the question isn't intended.